# psql update timestamp to nil

Tags: ruby, psql

I'm trying to update timestamp to nil, as my codebase tests for `user.last_seen.nil?` so I want to be able to reset my test users `last_seen` table value to nil. I've tried the following, where 'users' is my table. This correctly updates the last_seen field to current time.

```
UPDATE users SET last_seen = current_timestamp WHERE 'fakeemail@fake.com' = email;
```

If I try:

```
    UPDATE users SET last_seen = nil WHERE 'fakeemail@fake.com' = email;
```

however I get the error: `ERROR:  column "nil" does not exist`

I've tried this 10 different ways and can't get it to update.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Postgres, like most RDBMS's, uses `null`, not `nil`. If you update your query like so it'll work:

```
UPDATE users SET last_seen = null WHERE 'fakeemail@fake.com' = email;
```